# After updating variable in my view Model my fragment editText does not update

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this working fine in my main activity but for some reason with my fragment it doesn't want to update the editText field after it is changed.  Inside my fragment_controls.xml file I have an editText inside my fragment like so:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/alarmTemp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textColor="@color/background"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="@{userModel.alarmTemp}"
     />
```

data section above it is:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="userModel"
            type="com.mycompany.myapp.UIViewModel"/>
    </data>
```

Then in my fragment's java code:

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Defines the xml file for the fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_controls, parent, false);    
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_controls, parent, false);
        userModel  = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UIViewModel.class);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        binding.setUserModel(userModel);

        View rootView = binding.getRoot();
        return rootView;
```

In my data model I set the alarmTemp like this:
        `alarmTemp.setValue(s)`;

And this works when you start it up, whatever value I give s will appear in my EditText.  But if I set it later on during operation it doesn't change. It does work for fields that are in my main activity though.  So I'm confused as to why it doesn't work in my fragment.

Oh and alarm temp is defined as so in the viewModel:

```
public MutableLiveData<String> alarmTemp = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

Comment: use observable for databinding. Mutable is for observe data change in activity/fragment

Comment: MutableLiveData should work as well. Can you try observe changes of your alarmTemp in fragment (with logcat) - is it really changing?

Comment: Hi I see in logcat that the value is changing.  I also tried creating another textEdit in my main activity that also ties to alarmTemp and that changes.  And if I switch the fragment in and out the new value will be set when I switch my fragment back in :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's not the case but there is suspicion that you're trying to share your UIViewModel between your activity and fragment.

In that case you have to deal with the same instance of UIViewModel, otherwise you could change data in your "activity-instance"-ViewModel and don't see any changes observing "fragment-instance"-ViewModel.

If it the source of trouble, you can get the same "activity"-ViewModel in your fragment with the next code ([link to documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)):

```
userModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(UIViewModel.class);
```

Comment: Ah that was it.  It threw me that I could hack around it by reloading the activity.  I was calling ViewModelProvider(this  instead of requireActivity().  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it possible to make it work with the fragment as the lifecycle owner of the ViewModel?